# Django REST framework user and pass for https://api.opensyllabus.org

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-requests, api-key

I simply wanted to get an API key in [text](https://api.opensyllabus.org/) but when I press login it says that I should enter user and pass for Django REST framework and it does not have any register button. Is there anyone who could help me with this?

I wanted to get an API key in [text](https://api.opensyllabus.org/) but when I press login it says that I should enter user and pass for Django REST framework and it does not have any register button.